# Groupby and aggregate dataframe rows containing lists

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to consolidate similar lists in a pandas dataframe into 1 row.  I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( {'A' : [1,1,2,2], 'B' : [["a","b"],["c","d"],["e","f"], 
["g","h"]]})
df2 = df.groupby(['A'], as_index=False).agg(list)
print(df2)
```

Which produces the following output:

```
   A                 B
0  1  [[a, b], [c, d]]
1  2  [[e, f], [g, h]]
```

This produces a list of lists in the output which is not what I want.

Is there an easy way to group by and aggregate the lists so I get 1 long list in column B so I get a dataframe like the below sample?

```
   A             B
0  1  [a, b, c, d]
1  2  [e, f, g, h]
```

Note:  It doesn't matter if the final lists in column B contain dupes.  They can be de-duped, or dupes can remain, either way works for my purposes.

Comment: May I know why you need one lone list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `sum`:

```
df.groupby('A', as_index=False).agg(sum)
```

Output:

```
   A             B
0  1  [a, b, c, d]
1  2  [e, f, g, h]
```

Comment: We do not need agg `df.groupby('A',as_index=False).sum()
`

Comment: @WeNYoBen indeed, i just realized that as well.

Comment: ahh!!  I assumed sum would attempt to add them up, however in hindsight you add lists together to concat them.  Thank you!!!

Comment: `.sum()` should be way faster then `agg(sum)`

Comment: you are correct.  .sum() is the way to go.  Thank you again!